# Use both Delete and Backspace in Macbook

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

<kbd>Delete</kbd> key in my MacBook Pro works as <kbd>backspace</kbd> in other Windows keyboards and
<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> works as 'delete forward' as an ordinary <kbd>delete</kbd> key in Windows keyboard.

How can I change the keyboard setting so that I can use both 'delete forward' and 'delete backward' using only one key-in?

For example, <kbd>Eject CD</kbd> key is rarely used, so I'd like to use this key as 'delete forward' key and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Eject CD</kbd> for ejecting  CD. Can I do something like this?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) to remap the eject key to forward delete.

Partway down this [List of Prepared Settings](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/list.html.en) are details under "Change Eject Key."

Comment: Eject keys also have a small delay by default, but it can be removed with [NoEjectDelay](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/noejectdelay.html.en).

Answer (score 1):

KeyRemap4Macbook is great, but it has way too much configurability and not very much documentation. I found [this other tutorial](http://heisencoder.net/2008/04/fixing-up-mac-key-bindings-for-windows.html) that lets me play around with the default keymapping in `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict`. This is both fast, and keyboard specific; which works very well for me